# AWS Cognito Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-identitypools

After succesfull Login in the website , user data is getting generated in the user pool but no in identity pool. All the configurations are made according to the AWS Document . Need help in understanding and solving the problem .

I tried AWS Documents , checked the code settings and AWS Configuration setting couple of times with my team but not able to solve it